# session variable that records an onclick element

Tags: php, session

Lets say i have 5 pages which has some hierarchy and all pages are in same folder. When i click on one page its going to another page in same folder.

Example
fruits.php is main page and banana.php, apple.php, orange.php & pineapple.php. All the later 4 has links in main page. I need to display navigation in all the pages like if its main page just main page. If its a banana i should display as Main_Page>>Fruits>>Banana ans so on how can i achieve if i have n number of hierarchies lets say flowers(lily.php, rose.php), Eatables(chocolates.php, biscuits.php) etc and all pages in same folder.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is. Could you show some code and explain what the desired behaviour is?

Comment: I get the question, but why do you need a session variable? Isn't this just getting down what item belongs in which group? For example, within apple.php, you just include a nav that has apple highlighted, and same with your other fruits.

Comment: @DaveChen are u telling me to hand code in each and every page of mine

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish what you're asking, but I'm not sure how session plays into this. An easy method is just, `fruit.php?item=apple`, `flower.php?item=lily`, and so on. You have the contents on fruits change (and you can just include the proper file). That way, the nav is constant, and you can just change what the contents are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make folders foreach category and have them in the main folder:

```
main/flowers
main/fruits
...
```

include php files in respective folders:

```
main/flowers/lily.php
main/fruits/apple.php
...
```

now use javascript to read the url of the current page:

```
var url = window.location;
var cat = url.split("/");
cat[cat.length - 1] = cat[cat.length - 1].split(".")[0]; // to remove ".php" part from "lily.php" and get "lily" to display
```

now you have those names in `cat` array, so you can display them in html as you need:

```
alert(cat[1]+"/"+cat[2]); // should popup something like fruits/Apple
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what you are trying to make is called "breadcrumb". If you google it in this words you'll have too many hits.

There are too many ways to achieve this according to your site scheme. If you have a collection of your pages in your DB you can find the hierarchy of pages to show in breadcrumb by querying the DB. If you don't have this, I can advise you to make a folder hierarchy as:

`Main
    |--fruits.php
    |--flowers.php
    |--Fruits
        |--apples.php
        |--bananas.php
    |--Flowers
        |--lily.php
        |--rose.php`

Then on each page you can show your folder hierarchy as breadcrumb. This may be an easy way to start.

Comment: I don't think there is a dynamic way else using DB then.